# When I run the test "rspec spec "In the console, I'll get a deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
describe Item do

  it 'calculates price according to a special formula' do
    item = Item.new('kettle', price: 200)
    item.price.should == 212
  end

end
```

Deprecation Warnings:

Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` with
`config.expect_with(:rspec) { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead. Called from E:/work/storeapp/spec/item_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in '.

If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 0.00505 seconds (files took 0.17058 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures

How this warning can be avoided?

Comment: What is your _Question_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the test in a new style:

```
expect(item.price).to eq 212
```

BTW. it seems you might doing sth quite risk/confusing. Once you assign 200 to the attribute, it will be more than confusing to see another value returned by a getter with a same name. Have you considered leaving the original method alone and defining a new one instead (like price_with_vat)?